# C# MVC ASP.NET Most Efficient way to get data from database with id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and databases, but I'm fairly certain the way that I'm getting data from the database is incredibly inefficient.

```
public class PokemonViewController : Controller
{
    private PokemonDayCareDBEntities1 db = new PokemonDayCareDBEntities1();

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Pokemon(int id)
    {
        var pkmn = db.PlayerPkmns.ToList();
        PlayerPkmn thispkmn = null;

        //get pokemon from database where id = id
        foreach (var item in pkmn)
        {
            if (item.Id == id)
            {
                thispkmn = item;
            }
        }

....
```

I have the unique ID of the Pokemon that resides in the PlayerPkmns table, but I'm looping through the **entire** table in order to find the matching ID.

Depending on how large the table, the time this takes to execute would increase.

I'm positive there's a better way - would anyone know if there is one (also, the syntax on how to use it)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to get familiar with **Linq-to-Entities** . btw the code you would need is `db.PlayerPkmns.Where(x=>x.Id  == id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: No need for the where - `FirstOrDefault` takes a predicate.

Comment: @Alex isn't that the same as using `where` I mean behind the scenes..

Comment: Technically yes, but there `.Where` is superfluous

Comment: @Alex I see it as a better readability.. For newbies at least..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault` is your friend here.

Change this:

```
var pkmn = db.PlayerPkmns.ToList();
```

To

```
var pkmn = db.PlayerPkmns.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

This will translate (roughly) into the following SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PlayerPkmns WHERE ID = @id
```

Comment: thank you! I know it was a basic question, but I wasn't sure about the syntax  (i think it's called a lambda expression)? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Most effecient way to retrieve an entity is to use the .Find()
Where primaryKey is the Id you are passing in.

`var PlayerPkmn= db.PlayerPkmns.Find(primaryKey)`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Linq to Entities, you should be able to use the `Where()` in combination with `FirstOrDefault()` :

```
var pkmn = db.PlayerPkmns.Where(x=>x.Id  == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

The way you are doing right now will cause all the records to be brought in memory which is not what you want i believe, and it will be much performant than the way you are doing right now, as with the way you are doing, it will load all records in to the memory.

Comment: There's no need to use `Where`: you can also pass a predicate ti `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @CarlesCompany there are multiple ways for doing that, in both case sql will be generated similar i guess and from db side only 1 row will be returned

Comment: @EhsanSajjad is right... unless there is no improvements in any metrics I think all the ways are acceptable..

Comment: If you use resharper, this will show up as a warning. I like a green light on all my files :)

Comment: unfortunately i don't have resharper :/

Comment: @EhsanSajjad True, it's the same. But you have to agree with me that my option is more terse and understandable. :-)

Comment: it's totally one's preference based

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that `PokemonDayCareDBEntities1` is an *Entity Framework Data Context*.
In that case you can use `db.PlayerPkmns.Find(id)` or `db.PlayerPkmns.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)` if you want to handle the case where the entity does not exist in the DB, `db.PlayerPkmns.Single(x => x.Id == id)` if you are sure that there is strictly one element in the DB (will throw if the entity does not exist).